# Accessing information from an HTTPS JSON file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I want to use information from what I believe is a JSON file, using JavaScript or some derivation of it.  This is the file:
https://mylularoe.com/llrapi/v3/get-inventory/

The file looks (snippet) like this:

```
{
    "3 Day Shipping - ANY": {
        "model": "3 Day Shipping - ANY",
...
        "quantities": {
            "": {
                "count": "52710",
...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to read the file and make an alert pop up with the count (in this case, 52710).

I think I'm to use JQuery, by adding:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

to the header.

By my investigation, I should be able to use JSON.parse(data) if I could access the string, but I can't seem to get that going.

I'm working with an HTML file on my local computer, but I don't believe that is relevant.

I will update the question with more information as required.  Thank you for your help.  I've used Stack Overflow a million times and this is my first attempt at asking a question.

Comment: If you're using jQuery you can use `$.getJSON`. That will attempt to fetch the file and parse it into a JS object. However, like any AJAX request, you will be subject to the cross-domain origin policy. The file should live on the same domain or, if it doesn't, output headers denoting that your domain (or all domains) can access it remotely.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I do not have the ability to adjust this file.  I assume it does not render permission to do this.  Is there a route that doesn't require a header in the file I'm trying to read?

Comment: Study some tutorials on ajax

Comment: Any client-side attempts at cross domain require a header explicitly allowing your domain access. If you don't have this, the other route is to fetch the file's contents via a server-side technology, e.g. PHP cURL, which is not subject to such limitations. Your JS would then call not this file directly, but a PHP proxy file which fetched and served it. In this regard, as far as JS is concerned, it's a local AJAX call.

Comment: OK thanks.  ajax it is.  I mostly just needed a push in the right direction.  Study time.

Comment: @Utkanos thank you kindly.  I will investigate that route.